# If ABCD is a square and M is any point on CD...

Tags: geometry

If $ABCD$ is a square and $M$ is any point on $CD$, the angle bisector of angle $BAM$ intersects $BC$ at $K$ then how to prove that $MA=DM + BK$.

Answer (score 1):

$\bf{Hint}$:

Use the identity

$$\frac{1}{\sin \theta} = \frac{1}{\tan \theta} + \tan \frac{\theta}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be the point such that $\mathcal B(K,B,E)$ and $BE=DM$. Prove that $ABE\cong ADM$, hence $AM=AE$. Then prove that $\angle EAK=\angle EKA$, hence $AE=EK$. Therefore, $AM= AE=EK=EB+BK=DM+BK$.

Comment: Hi, Is the point B supposed to be read as a vector? Or was it a typo error? Thanks

Comment: @GuoJinLong Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Can you be more precise?

Comment: What do you mean by B(K, B, E)? It has 3 coordinates so do i interpret it as a vector? But the rest of your solutions do not make further reference to this vector.

Comment: @GuoJinLong Oh, that. No, it is "between relation". It says that K, B and E are collinear points, and B is between K and E.